# ¿Que alternativas tengo para hacer una transicion de un degradado en un botón?

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Tengo un problema, he investigado y leí que css aun no admite **transition** en css... Entonces tengo un botón con solo un borde degradado y quiero que al hacer hover el botón se rellene completo de ese degradado... Hay alguna forma alterna de crearlo¿? A continuacion les dejo el codigo que tengo...

```css
.servicios_btn{
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 45px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: solid 3px transparent;
  background-image:linear-gradient(#ffffff, #ffffff), linear-gradient(78deg, #102397 , #00EAF8);
  background-position: 0 100%;
  transition: background-position 0.5s;
  /*background-image: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #ffffff), linear-gradient(to right, #00c6ff, #53a0fd 48%, #0072ff);*/
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
  
}
.servicios_btn a{
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #0b457f; 
  margin-top: 7px;
}


.servicios_btn:hover{
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.servicios_btn:hover a{
    color:white;

}
```

```html
<div class="servicios_btn">
  <a href="#">Servicios</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una buena alternativa sería lo que sugiere [Hugo Quiñónez en su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/186754/250): que sea el elemento `<a>` el que tiene un fondo blanco y que este desaparezca cambiándolo a transparente. Como alternativa a su alternativa, podrías usar `box-shadow` en el `<a>` para eso. Algo como esto:

```css
.servicios_btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #00EAF8, #102397);
  display: flex;
}

.servicios_btn a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #0b457f;
  line-height: 34px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 3px;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 20px white;
}

.servicios_btn:hover a {
  color:white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 20px transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="servicios_btn">
  <a href="#">Servicios</a>
</div>
```

¿Por qué sugiero `box-shadow`? Porque es una [propiedad animable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties) (a la que se le pueden aplicar animaciones/transiciones) que te va a dar más juego que el simple color de fondo: no sólo podrás controlar el color, sino también la dirección o el difuminado que quieres que se aplique al cambio. Lo cual puede dar más juego a la hora de crear un botón animado.

Aquí puedes ver como algunos ejemplos:

```css
.servicios_btn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #00EAF8, #102397);
  display: flex;
}

.servicios_btn a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #0b457f;
  line-height: 34px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 3px;
  transition: box-shadow 0.5s;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 20px white;
}

.servicios_btn.izq-der a {
  box-shadow: inset -200px 0px 10px 0px white;
}

.servicios_btn.der-izq a {
  box-shadow: inset 200px 0px 10px 0px white;
}

.servicios_btn.top-bottom a {
  box-shadow: inset 0px -40px 10px 0px white;
}

.servicios_btn.bottom-top a {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 40px 10px 0px white;
}

.servicios_btn:hover a {
  color:white;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0 10px -10px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="servicios_btn">
  <a href="#">Servicios</a>
</div>

<div class="servicios_btn izq-der">
  <a href="#">Servicios</a>
</div>

<div class="servicios_btn der-izq">
  <a href="#">Servicios</a>
</div>

<div class="servicios_btn top-bottom">
  <a href="#">Servicios</a>
</div>

<div class="servicios_btn bottom-top">
  <a href="#">Servicios</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Elegante solución. Yo hubiera usado un seudoelemento pero creo que es porque se convirtieron en mi Martillo de Maslow

Comment: Excelente aportación

Comment: @amenadiel esa sería también una buena alternativa y sería mejor que ésta porque podrías jugar con las transformaciones y las posibilidades serían innumerables. Deberías ponerlo como respuesta.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ahí puse mi solución. Creo que es menos elegante y más trabajosa, pero tener varias alternativas puede ayudar al visitante que lea esta pregunta en el futuro remoto

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurre hacer transparente el color del `<a>` y agregarle un fadein, no sé si te sirve.

```css
.servicios_btn {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 45px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: solid 3px transparent;
  background: linear-gradient(78deg, #102397, #00EAF8);
  background-origin: border-box;      
}

.servicios_btn a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #0b457f;
  position: relative;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 80px;
  transition: all 300ms;
  /* la duración de la transición */
}

.servicios_btn:hover a {
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="servicios_btn">
  <a href="#">Servicios</a>
</div>
```

Espero te sirva

Answer (score 1):

Esta solución ocupa un seudoelemento posicionado después del div mediante `.servicios_btn:after`. Tiene el color que quieres ponerle al contenedor cuando se hace hover sobre él y posicionamiento relativo para alinearse con éste. Su opacidad inicial es cero, pero al hacer hover (`.servicios_btn:hover:after`) la opacidad transiciona a 1.

La idea de las transiciones (y por eso un background-image no se puede transicionar) es que el browser pueda interpolar entre los dos estados. Una imagen no es interpolable, incluso tratándose de un degradado definido por colores hexadecimales que en sí son interpolables.

El link dentro del contenedor también tiene `position:relative` porque necesito asegurarme de que tenga un z-index tal que quede por encima del seudoelemento.

Puse esta solución a sugerencia de [Álvaro Montoro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/250/alvaro-montoro) aunque en realidad puede que sea sobrecomplicarse la vida por el trabajo que conlleva alinear perfectamente el seudoelemento.

```css
.servicios_btn{
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 45px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: solid 3px transparent;
  background-image:linear-gradient(#ffffff, #ffffff), linear-gradient(78deg, #102397 , #00EAF8);
  background-position: 0 100%;
  transition: background-position 0.5s;
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box, border-box;
  
}
.servicios_btn a{
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #0b457f; 
  margin-top: 7px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2;
}

.servicios_btn:after {
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    height: 42px;
    width: 205px;
    background-position: 0 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(78deg, #102397 , #00EAF8);
    top: -36px;
    left: -3px;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-clip: content-box, border-box;
    border-radius: 100px;
    z-index:1;
    transition:opacity 0.5s;
}

.servicios_btn:hover:after {
  opacity:1;
}
.servicios_btn:hover{
  background-position: 0 0;
}

.servicios_btn:hover a{
    color:white;

}
```

```html
<div class="servicios_btn">
  <a href="#">Servicios</a>
</div>
```